# Is there measurable bijection?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Let $X$ be a measurable space, and let $Y$ be a topological space.

> If $X$, $Y$ have the same cardinality, is there (necessarily) a measurable bijection from $X$ to $Y$?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. If the sigma algebra on $X$ is countably generated  then the sigma algebra on $Y$ would have to be countably generated  for the existence of  measurable bijection. [ Countably generated means there is sequence $(A_n)$ such that the given sigma algebra equals $\sigma(A_1,A_2,...)$].

Note that irrespective of the cardinality of $X$ we can always fine countably generated sigma algebra on $X$ so all you need is to take $Y$ to have a non-countably generated sigma algebra.

Comment: But Y is a topological space...

Comment: First of all you did not say what sigma algebra you are considering on the topological space. Secondly, even if you are taking the Borel sigma algebra it does not follow that this sigma algebra is countably generated. So my counter-exmple is very general. @JohnMars

Comment: Sorry, This is my first approach to measure-theory. I have the following definition: A measurable function is a function from a measurable space to a topological space that 'return' open sets in measurable sets. Where we need a sigma algebra on Y?

Comment: @JohnMars In that case you are taking the Borel sigma algebra  on $Y$. [It is the sigma algebra generated by open sets].

Comment: How a sigma algebra in Y affect the measurability (of the function in question) under this definition?